# nginx configuration for three types of .php files

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config

I have three types of url like this :

http://log.cb.gq/index.php/creative-thinking-workshop-de

http://log.cb.gq/work.php/creative-thinking-workshop-de

http://log.cb.gq/cat.php/creative-thinking-workshop-de

and nginx conf is like this

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
            #rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?$1;
    }
```

and only first url ie index.php work. How can I make all three work

Comment: What happens for the other URLs? Do you get a certain status code from Nginx? Or do you get a PHP-level error?

Comment: its showing content of index.php and route of work.php/creative-thinking-workshop-de and ofcource no css

Comment: but its working ok on localhost with apache with no htaccess

Comment: So the pages are loading, just not the resources? If so, check the server and/or browser console logs for errors, and look into the paths that they are trying to load from.

Comment: The correct solution is to change the `location ~ \.php$` block so that it matches the URIs in your question. [For example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) with: `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$)`

Answer (score 0):

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /work.php {
try_files $uri $uri/ /work.php$is_args$args;
}

location /cat.php {
try_files $uri $uri/ /cat.php$is_args$args;
}

This worked for me